# How to Properly Use "Sign In With Google" Button on Django Web App using Django all-auth

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-allauth

In my Django web app(Currently not in production), i want to use all-auth for signing in users with their Google account and that is working by using the below form for social account.

//templates/socialaccount/login.html

```
{% extends "socialaccount/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
<h1 class="display-4">{% blocktranslate with provider.name as provider %}Sign In Via {{ provider }}{% endblocktranslate %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktranslate with provider.name as provider %}You are about to sign in from {{ provider }}.{% endblocktranslate %}</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{% translate "Sign In" %}</button>
    
</form>
```

after clicking on sign in button it is opening the new url like - `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=5649........apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Faccounts%2Fgoogle%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&scope=profile&response_type=code&state=ch...kO&access_type=online&service=lso&o2v=2&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow`

that's asking me to choose the Google account, after i select my account it signs me in and redirect to the django app's homepage.

which is working as expected,
But after reading the Google Brand Guidelines, i came to know we should use the sign in with google button that comply their guidelines
like in their documentation - https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button

So how can i use that button that will comply Google's guidelines for signing in and does not disturb the login and authentication flow.

i create the button with Google button generator for sign in and used in the login template
but this seems to be not working.

//templates/socialaccount/login.html

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {% if provider.name == 'Google' %}
    
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="105.......apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

    
    {% else %}
    
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{% translate "Sign In" %}</button>
    {% endif %}
    
</form>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

using this i can see the Sign in with Google button, but it is not working.
So How can i Properly set up this in development server as well as in production server?

For reference you can see-
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference

Inside my project settings.py file

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        },
    }
}


SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/google/login/'


SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '564.....apps.googleusercontent.com'  
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'GOC....'


ACCOUNT_MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESSES = 1 


ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

Answer (score 2):

Searched also for a solution for some time. I've ended up with the following approach:

- getting the styling "code" from google [Google Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines)
- creating a custom.css file and add the css part from above
- get the template file from [allauth repository](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/allauth/templates/socialaccount/login.html) and copied it into `templates/socialaccount/login.html`
- Removed this `{% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}` and added the HTML-Snippet from google instead.
- added `<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">` around the button

This way, every additional login source (IDP) must be added in the `login.html` as well. This tradeoff should be acceptable as every new IDP will need it's own button anyway, so manual effort will be needed.